# Connection attempt failed when connecting to MongoDB deployment from mongo shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, amazon-web-services

first question and complete beginner so apologies in advanced for any silly mistakes.

I have created a server on Amazon Web Services and then linked that through the MongoDB Cloud Manager where I made a replica set.

I have been following the tutorial on the mongoDB cloud documentation but have become stuck on the final part - "Connect to a MongoDB Process".

It says "Cloud Manager provides a mongo shell command that you can use to connect to the MongoDB process if you are connecting from the system where the deployment runs" - Can I not do this because the deployment is running on the Amazon Server?

When I enter the mongo shell command this is what it reads:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4
connecting to: AM-0.amigodb.0813.mongodbdns.com:27001/AmigoMain_1
2015-08-07T18:41:56.806+0100 W NETWORK  
Failed to connect to 52.18.23.14:27001 after 5000 milliseconds, giving up.
2015-08-07T18:41:56.809+0100 E QUERY    
Error: couldn't connect to server AM-0.amigodb.0813.mongodbdns.com:27001       (52.18.23.14), connection attempt failed
at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181:14)
at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:181
exception: connect failed
```

I followed the instructions for the security settings on the Amazon Web Service but thinking that I may well have made a mistake.

Would greatly appreciate any help or where to go for answers.

Thanks,

Louis

Answer (score 0):

Mongo by default only listens to connections on localhost. You'll need to edit mongo.conf and add your IP to the "bind ip" setting.

Answer (score 0):

This is my mongod.conf file:

```
processManagement:
   fork: true
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
storage:
   dbPath: "/data/db"
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/var/log/mongod.log"
   logAppend: true
storage:
   journal:
        enabled: true
```

It also gave me the same error message when I changed my bindIp to 0.0.0.0